# Address already in use Unity Android

Tags: c#, android, http, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run an HTTP Listener in an Android application, while I get an exception

> SocketException: Address already in use

Unity Player does not produce errors, just like the build for Windows. netstat on the device shows. that the port is not occupied by anyone, what could be the problem?
Maybe something needs to be added to the manifest?

My code  (port 37273)

```
 private void Listen()
{
    Debug.Log("START HTTP LISTENIER!");
    listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:" + port.ToString() + "/");
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:" + port.ToString() + "/");
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:" + port.ToString() + "/");
    listener.Start();
    while (connect)
    {
        try
        {
            Process(listener.GetContext());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("HTTP listener context Exeption: " + ex.ToString() + "\n  " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

StackTrace

> 05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   : SocketException: Address already in use
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint localEP) [0x00043] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.EndPointListener..ctor (System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Net.IPAddress addr, System.Int32 port, System.Boolean secure) [0x00047] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.EndPointManager.GetEPListener (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Boolean secure) [0x0009d] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddPrefixInternal (System.String p, System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0005e] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddListener (System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0009c] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start () [0x0000f] in <0813754e7cfa415ebfedff172c2dd6e0>:0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at WebServer.Listen () [0x00093] in :0
>   05-08 07:42:15.751  4606  4699 E Unity   :   at System.Threading.ThreadHe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved, for some reason Unity ignored my Security config, and inserted its own, changing cleartextTrafficPermitted to false

Comment: I am using the code in a very similar way but after ensuring that cleartextTraffitPermitted=true, the debuger still gives me the SocketException: Address already in use Error.

Comment: I noticed I only get my error when listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:" + port.ToString() + "/"); is included

Answer (score 1):

Check if this code is being called only once, because calling this twice would have the listener occupy the same port.